# What decides the number of jobs in a spark application

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Previously my understanding was , an action will create a job in spark application. But let's see below scenario where I am just creating a dataframe using .range() method

```
df=spark.range(10)
```

Since my spark.default.parallelism is 10, resultant dataframe is of 10 partitions.
Now I am just performing a .show()  and .count() actions on dataframe

```
df.show()
df.count()
```

Now when I have checked spark history I can see 3 jobs for .show() and 1 job for .count()

[image]

Why 3 jobs are here for .show() method?

I have read some where  .show() will eventually call .take() internally and it will iterate through partitions which decides the number of jobs . But I didn't  understand that part?
What exactly decides the number of jobs ?